# jQuery: catching jsonp 400 Bad Request?

Tags: jquery, http-status-code-400

How to catch 400 header and process error callback on jsonp request?

Or it's a bug?

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/pLuPb/

Neither error, neither complete is triggered? How to catch error?

I'm cursed? Last week i'm getting this kind of problems... :D

Guess i'll have to report this one to jQuery tracker.

Thanks ;)

Comment: I think it's not JSONP problem but youtube'S mistake. Where did you get this API address?

Comment: You don't get it. It doesn't matter what url is it. If it's invalid i should catch Bad Request from Google, log bad link and show message to user.

Comment: Does google have video id matching pattern? So that i can check id via pattern and then launch ajax? Guess not.

Comment: It does. Look here http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/7lS121asdf231231213b4uo6wQM?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=jQuery1608265016433579725_1308398370389&_=1308398370655 it will return "File not found", and that's youtube'S problem. It returns 400 to your ajax handler

Comment: So is there a solution for invalid youtube links?

Comment: I was asking - Wheer did you get that link ?

Answer (score 5):

jsopn is not regular  ajax request, it actually creates a script tag in ur DOM that's the reason jsonp response data is in format **abc_FunctionName(data)**, and you gat get data directly into that function. But jQuery does that for you automatcally so you never come across that part.

To handle jsonp errors use this pluggin http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/

Answer (score 2):

JSONP is not like regular AJAX requests it uses a script tag to get the content. That being said, jQuery should be able to catch an error like 400 and its strange that its not.

You may want to add a timeout in your ajax config object: http://jsfiddle.net/pLuPb/18/

You could also do something like your own JSONP handler: http://jsfiddle.net/6j6uk/ (not sure about X-Browser support)