# Function didn't trigger?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I have this ajax call in my js. With this request I want to know if there is a previous opened session, in that case it will show the login form.

So, if there is no previous session, the server returns error 400 bad request (laravel response class). But when the server returns, the $.ajax object does not trigger the error function. Anyone knows why?

**Server response**

```
$data =[
  'error' => [
    'message' => 'Authentication Error',
    'statusCode' => 400
  ]
]
Response::json($data, 400, [])
  ->setCallback(Input::get('callback'));
```

**Ajax request**

```
$.ajax({
  global: true,
  method: 'POST',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  url: 'http://localhost:8082/api/checkAuth?callback=?',
  success: function(response) {
    return console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    return console.log(c);
  }
});
```

I tried too getting the status code to trigger a function, but it does not work anyway:

** Ajax Request **

```
$.ajax({
  global: true,
  method: 'POST',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  url: 'http://localhost:8082/api/checkAuth?callback=?',
  success: function(response) {
    return console.log(response);
  },
  statusCode:{
    400: function(a,b,c){
      console.log(a);
      console.log(b);
      console.log(c);
    }
  }
});
```

Thank you guys, for the help

SOME UPDATES:

Thanks to manish, I discovered this [plugin](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp) for handling jsonp request, that triggers the error function. Does anyone know a way to capture the returned status code in the error function?

Comment: press `F12` in your browser and select the "network" tab to check if the server is really answering and what's the status code js is getting.

Comment: Already done, the request responds 400, and if i change the resposne code from the server to 200, the success function triggers like a charm.

Comment: `return console.log(response);` The `return` makes no sense.

Comment: That's how coffeescript compile it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the server is returning 400 because it expects a POST request, jsonp is only capable of sending GET requests. Instead of using jsonp, you might want to use [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Comment: I am (on purpose) returning statuscode 400, I am having trouble with the error handling, not avoiding the status code 400. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Man I finally abandoned the jsonp to use CORS, as you said. Thanks for your answer again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your code, it is how json and jsonp responses are handled. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395821/jquery-catching-jsonp-400-bad-request) to get idea how to handle error response. You can use [this plugin](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp) 
to handle jsonp request-responses

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks man, I used the plugin you suggested an works well. I want to capture the statusCode when the error is produced just to filter a 400 (what means login failure) or other statusCode. ¿do you know how?